# C# MVC ActionResult that returns multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can an MVC `ActionResult` return multiple files? If so, can it return multiple files, of multiple type?

Examples:
   Can an `ActionResult` return myXMLfile1.xml, myXMLfile2.xml, and myfile3.xml?

Can an `ActionResult` return myXMLfile4.xml, and myTXTfile1.txt?

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: One method to accomplish this is to create a zip file containing all the files you want to return, and just return that as a single file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot return multiples files, but, you can compact multiple files in a `.zip` file and return this compacted file, for sample, create a custom ActionResult in your project, like this:

```
public class ZipResult : ActionResult
{
    private IEnumerable<string> _files;
    private string _fileName;

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileName ?? "file.zip";
        }
        set { _fileName = value; }
    }

    public ZipResult(params string[] files)
    {
        this._files = files;
    }

    public ZipResult(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        this._files = files;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        using (ZipFile zf = new ZipFile())
        {
            zf.AddFiles(_files, false, "");
            context.HttpContext
                .Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            context.HttpContext
                .Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
            zf.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }

}
```

And use it like this:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var zipResult = new ZipResult(
        Server.MapPath("~/Files/file1.xml"),
        Server.MapPath("~/Files/file2.xml"),
        Server.MapPath("~/Files/file3.xml")
    );
    zipResult.FileName = "result.zip";

    return zipResult;
}
```

See more here: http://www.campusmvp.net/blog/asp-net-mvc-return-of-zip-files-created-on-the-fly

Comment: Thanks Felipe! Is a ZipResult the same as a gzip file?

Comment: As we can see on the code I've posted above, `ZipResult` class uses the `SharpZipLib` library to compact the file, you can find it on NuGet and add the reference on your application. You also could change the way to compact files, but the main idea is the same :).